# Adding images from an external gallery to a SilverStripe site via a BuildTask

Tags: silverstripe

I'm making a Silverstripe build task to get many images from an external gallery, and create/upload them into the `/assets/images/gallery` folder with the necessary database links to the `GalleryPage`.

So I load the list of Urls, display the images to the browser, now how do I save an image into the assets folder with the necessary `GalleryPage` database links?

```
class ImportGalleryTask extends BuildTask {
    public function writeImage($data) {
        //$data->Title
        //$data->Filename
        //$data->Url
        //this is the external url that I can output as an image to the browser
        //
        // folder to save image is 'assets/images/gallery'
        //
        // ? save into folder and database and associate to PageImageBelongsToID  ?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`copy`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) to copy a remote file to your local filesystem. PHP must be configured to support [`allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) though.

So, your resulting function might look like this:

```
/**
 * @param $data
 * @return null|Image return written Image object or `null` if failed
 */
public function writeImage($data) 
{
    // The target folder for the image
    $folder = Folder::find_or_make('images/gallery');

    // assuming that $data->Filename contains just the file-name without path
    $targetPath = $folder->getFullPath() . $data->Filename;

    // Check if an image with this name already exists
    // ATTENTION: This will overwrite existing images! 
    // If you don't want this, you need to implement this differently
    if(
        file_exists($targetPath) &&
        $image = Image::get()->where(array(
            '"Name" = ?' => $data->Filename, 
            '"ParentID" = ?' => $folder->ID
        ))->first()
    ){
        // just copy the new file over…
        copy($data->Url, $targetPath);
        // … and delete all cached images
        $image->deleteFormattedImages();
        // and we're done
        return $image;
    }

    // Try to copy the file
    if (!copy($data->Url, $targetPath)) {
        return null;
    }

    // Write the file to the DB
    $image = Image::create(array(
        'Name' => $data->Filename,
        'ParentID' => $folder->ID,
        'Filename' => $folder->getRelativePath() . $data->Filename
    ));

    $image->write();
    return $image;
}
```

Comment: Great thanks, this works for copying the image and recognizing it in the database, however it doesn't associate it with the page it should belong to, that is the GalleryPage.  The image needs to belong to GalleryImage class, GalleryImage class has a PageImageBelongsToID which is a GalleryPage class, how would I do that?

Comment: @user3257693 Well, it depends. If you have a single GalleryPage, then you can just get it: `GalleryPage::get()->first()`. Otherwise you'll somehow have to tell the import task which GalleryPage you want to import to… maybe be passing the ID as parameter.

Comment: @user3257693 also, subclassing Image to create a relation is a really bad idea. I think there are several cases where the system will create an `Image` for you, and not your desired subclass (eg. if you replace your image via CMS). I strongly advise you to use an extension instead and probably also a `many_many` relation, so that you can attach an Image to multiple pages.